# How to save data to same line using imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am using this codes which extract from different pages, but I want to extract in the same line and in this moment every extract is saved in new line.

How can I save the extracted data to same line?

```
iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{town}} \nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=orders_{{!NOW:dd-mm-yyyy}}.csv");

iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{edu}} \nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=orders_{{!NOW:dd-mm-yyyy}}.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{town}}");
var town = iimGetExtract();

iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{edu}}");
var edu = iimGetExtract();

iimSet("town", town);
iimSet("edu", edu);
iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{town}}[EXTRACT]{{edu}} \nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=orders_{{!NOW:dd-mm-yyyy}}.csv");
```